# Cannot convert ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<java.lang.String>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I have an odd (in my mind) problem. I am currently making a Custom JComboBoxModel for some custom functionality I need from a Custom Renderer I am not yet certain how to deal with, I will post regarding that later.

Regardless, as the Title suggested I am getting some Type errors.

Here is the classes (current) code:

```
package miscclasses;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

public class CustomComboBoxModel<String> extends AbstractListModel<String> {
    /**
     * Contains a list of row indexes that shouldn't be displayed.
     */
    private ArrayList<String> alreadySelectedIndexes;
    /**
     * The comboBoxes selected index.
     */
    private int selectedIndex=-1;
    /**
     * Contains a list of values in this model.
     */
    private ArrayList<String> vals;
    /**
     * Creates an empty CustomComboBoxModel.
     */
    public CustomComboBoxModel() {
        this.alreadySelectedIndexes=new ArrayList<>();
        this.vals = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    /**Creates a CustomComboBoxModel with the values passed in.
     * 
     * @param values the row values.
     */
    public CustomComboBoxModel(ArrayList<String> values) {
        this();
        this.vals.addAll(values);
    }

    public CustomComboBoxModel(ArrayList<String> values, ArrayList<String> alreadySelected) {
        this(values);
        this.alreadySelectedIndexes.addAll(alreadySelected);
    }

    public CustomComboBoxModel(ArrayList<String> values, ArrayList<String> alreadySelected, int selectedIndex) {
        this(values, alreadySelected);
        this.selectedIndex=selectedIndex;
    }

    public CustomComboBoxModel(ArrayList<String> values, ArrayList<String> alreadySelected, String selectedValue) {
        this(values, alreadySelected);
        if(!this.vals.isEmpty()) {
            //this.selectedIndex = Misc.containsI(this.vals, selectedValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return this.vals.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementAt(int i) {
        return this.vals.get(i);
    }

    public boolean isRowSelected(int i) {
        return ((!this.alreadySelectedIndexes.contains(Integer.toString(i)))?false:true);
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is on line 55 where I attempt to get the selected values index. This is the commented line in the constructor that accepts two ArrayList lists and a String value. The error states that there is "no suitable method for containsI(java.util.ArrayList,String) method miscclasses.Misc.containsI(java.util.ArrayList, java.lang.String) is not applicable".

So far as I know String and java.lang.String are the exact same thing. As such I cannot seem to figure out what could cause this issue, and thought I would come to ask those more knowledgeable in the ways of Code-fu than I.

For reference, the Misc.containsI(ArrayList,String) code is here:

```
 /**
 * Finds the index of value Target. Returns -1 if this ArrayList doesn't contain Target.
 * @param a         ArrayList of Strings a.
 * @param target    Value to find.
 * @return          Index of target if found; Else returns -1.
 */
public static int containsI(ArrayList<String> a, String target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if(a.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(target))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am also strangely receiving the following warning in my isRowSelected(int i) function:
"Suspcious call to java.util.Collection.contains: Expected type String, actual type String".

Again, I don't understand why I am getting warning. It seems to be entirely valid code, and I have done similar before. Any help with this odd warning and error, would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Changing the Declaration so it reads:

```
public class CustomComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel<String>
```

instead of:

```
public class CustomComboBoxModel<String> extends AbstractListModel<String>
```

Appears to have gotten rid of the warning and error. I do not understand why however, as I have a Custom JList mode declared as such:

```
public class CustomListModel<String> extends javax.swing.DefaultListModel<String>
```

In the same package with no errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On this line you have declared a type parameter called `String`:

```
public class CustomComboBoxModel<String> extends AbstractListModel<String> {
                                 ^^^^^^
```

When you later refer to `String` the compiler thinks you mean the type parameter, not the  `java.lang.String` class.

The solution here is to remove the type parameter, since you do not need a type parameter.

---

The following simplified example gives a similar error message:

```
class Foo<String>
{
    String s = ""; // error: incompatible types
}
```

The full error message is:

```
Main.java:3: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: String
    String s = "";
               ^
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/CmG17)

Comment: Mentioning that does make sense, given the wording of the error and warning. Oddly though, I have no such class however, trying that in other classes in this package caused the same error.
For whatever reason however, changing the class declaration from "public class CustomComboBoxModel<String> extends AbstractListModel<String>" to "public class CustomComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel<String>"
I don't quite understand why this is though. Thank you for your help however, as I never would have tried that without you mentioning that. EDIT: Do you know why changing that got rid of the issue?

Comment: @Legowaffles: Ah I see it now. You created `String` as a type parameter for the class. You should get at least half the credit for solving this one!

Comment: Whats the difference between this and the JList model I mentioned above, aside from one extending a Default model? I don't quite understand the difference. See my edit to the main post for more details.

Comment: @Legowaffles: That syntax on its own is not incorrect - it's perfectly valid to have a type parameter called `String` and in some cases it might compile and even run without problems. The issue is if you have some code inside the class like `String s = "";`. Then you get a type error because the literal string has the real `java.lang.String` type and that can't be assigned to your `String` type.

Comment: Hmmm, if my understanding is correct, then it might be wise to remove the <String> from CustomListModel<String> in my custom JList model class, to attempt to prevent future issues that may otherwise occur.

EDIT: Sure enough, trying something similar in my Custom JList model is causing the same error. Thanks a lot for the assistance.